# Heroku SSL redirect for MEAN app

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have a MEAN app on Heroku. I want to ensure all traffic is going via HTTPS.

I have tried two npm modules

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-ssl-redirect

In my app.js file I did the following

```
var sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// enable ssl redirect
app.use(sslRedirect());
```

this is then used in www file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('node-rest:server');
var http = require('http');
var sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');
var enforce = require('express-sslify');



var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);




/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

I can't seem to get the app to redirect and thus if people use the url with https it servers them a warning

Comment: Tried writing manually with a npm module but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce SSL before the express.static

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and then it works great